# Временно отключить обработчик MouseDown

Tags: c#, unity3d

В Match3 игрушке перемещаем кубики. Если во время перемещения кубиков щёлкнуть еще на один - перемещение останавливается. Еще разок - и третий кубик начинает двигаться как второй. Пока ищу причину сей баги, возник вопрос - а не проще ли отключить щелчки мышкой, пока кубики летают с места на место? И как подобное реализовать на тачскрине?

```
 public void OnMouseDown() {



    //Если этот кубик не был выбран - он выбирается 
    if (!isSelected && (myController.selectedPieces[0] == null || myController.selectedPieces[1]== null))// Вроде бы должен не выбирать кубик, если массив заполнен, но он всё равно выбирается. 
    {

        isSelected = true;


    }
    else {
        //Если кубик был выбран ранее и щёлкнули на него же - он перестает быть выбранным

        isSelected = false;
        isMoving = false; /
    }
    myController.selected(this.gameObject, isSelected);

    //Вызываем скрипт gameController, передавая ему информацию о кубике. Вызван или не вызван. 

}
```

Comment: Ну выставьте булев флаг, в чём загвоздка-то?

Comment: @VladD чуть более подробно, прошу. Я знаю что такое булева переменная, но как отключить с её помощью void - не знаю.

Comment: `public void OnMouseDown() { if (isMoving) return; ...... остальная логика  }`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Решил. Оформил так - поставил статическую публичную булеву переменную dontmouse и когда она false - мышка работает, когда нет - то нет.  `public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if (Globalki.dontmouse == false)
        {
            

                     if (!isSelected && (myController.selectedPieces[0] == null || myController.selectedPieces[1] == null))
            {
                
                isSelected = true; Ну и так далее. Спасибо! Почему на некоторых вопросах вы даете правильные комментарии, но не оформляете ответы? `

Comment: Ну как бы это известная техника, поэтому раз вы спрашиваете, есть шанс, что вы ею воспользовались, но есть тонкости, из-за которых она не сработала.

Comment: @VladD Да нет, я просто затупил) Опыта мало, поэтому портировать даже уже использовавшиеся решения на новые задачи не всегда очевидно для меня) Для тачпада решение ничем не отличается?

Comment: @Dmitrii Нет, по идее ничем отличаться не должно.

Comment: У вас отключение активного объекта если щелкнули по другому кубику выполняется в `myController`? По идее ваш обработчик срабатывает только для того объекта по которому кликнули, если другие кубики ведут себя не адекватно, значит проблема в контроллере который управляет текущим кубиком.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, вам нужен такой паттерн:

```
bool isMoving = false; // static по идее не нужен
public void OnMouseDown()
{
    if (isMoving)
        return;
    try
    {
        isMoving = true;
        // тут остальной код
    }
    finally
    {
        isMoving = false;
    }
}
```

`try`/`finally` нужен для того, чтобы сбросить `isMoving` даже если метод отработает с исключением.